# Javascript: Duplicate div in html, replace hardcoded text within, and append to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I able to duplicate a div in html and replace a hardcoded text within the div. After its duplicated I want to append them to a another div. I have my code below however its not working for me. Please help.

HTML

```
<div id="studentInfo" style="border:1px solid black;">
  <ul>
      <li>Raven</li>
      <li>James</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="addBtn">Add Student</button>
<div id="block" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black;">
  <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Achievers</p>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('#addBtn').click(function(){
    var firstname = 'Stack';
    var lastname = 'overflow';

    var studentDiv = $('#studentInfo').clone(true);

    var children = studentDiv.children('ul li');
    studentDiv.find(children).val(firstname);
    studentDiv.find(children).val(lastname);

    $('#block').append(studentDiv).html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st** With li use `.text()` not `.val()`

**2nd**  Use `:nth-child()` selector to determine the selected li you need

try this code

```
$('#addBtn').click(function(){
    var firstname = 'Stack';
    var lastname = 'overflow';

    var studentDiv = $('#studentInfo').clone(true);
    studentDiv.find('ul > li:nth-child(1)').text(firstname);
    studentDiv.find('ul > li:nth-child(2)').text(lastname);

    $('#block').append(studentDiv);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/5a3rrfpx/)

Comment: What if I have several student info div? will it clone them all resulting to multiple clones instead of one only?

Comment: @Raven you mean you want to change data each time you append??

Comment: @Raven 1st I should say id must be unique so don't duplicate ids .. if you need to change data each time https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/5a3rrfpx/2/  ... if you have mulitple student you should loop through the divs https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/5a3rrfpx/3/

Comment: Actually the student info div is iterated meaning it has multiple div's with each having a different data set on the ul li tag. As I tried the code you had given, the replacement which is the "stack" and "overflow" are also iterated but the data is constant. Is there other ways to do cloning? how if we based it directly on the html? thank you

Comment: Based on the second link that you've given, how If I only want to clone one of the students. As I click the add button, I want to append student 1 (raven, james) only without appending the others through js?

Comment: @Raven https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/5a3rrfpx/5/ you can change .eq(0) to eq(1)...etc up to your need

Comment: Thank you Sir, it worked. I just want to ask if you have any ideas aside from cloning in recreating another div using javascript?

Comment: @Raven look Raven I think you didn't explain well what you trying to do .. let me tell you what I assuming you do .. you create a list from students and want to make click event to add the student to another div depending on which student div  user will choose .. right??

Comment: All is working fine now. Im just asking if you have any ideas in recreating a div without using cloning? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#addBtn').click(function() {
  var firstname = 'Stack';
  var lastname = 'overflow';

  var studentDiv = $('#studentInfo').clone(true);

  var children = studentDiv.find('ul li');
  children.eq(0).html(firstname);
  children.eq(1).html(lastname);

  $('#block').append(studentDiv);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="studentInfo" style="border:1px solid black;">
  <ul>
    <li>Raven</li>
    <li>James</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="addBtn">Add Student</button>
<div id="block" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; border:1px solid black;">
  <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">Achievers</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I have several student info div? will it clone them all resulting to multiple clones instead of one only?